# Format Excel Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was given this data from an Excel File. I tried text to columns but given the multiple modifiers (tabs, spaces, etc.) it made the data worse. It looks like this all in one column. :

```
Abadia, Fermin  ............................................ 11 0 0 0 8,062 Abbott, Tony  ................................................ 6 0 0 1 2,115 Abbott, III, Francis  ...................................... 79 9 8 11 374,602
```

Is there a way to format the data that it lines up like this

```
 Column A        Column B    Column C  Column D  Column E  Column F
 Abadia, Fermin       11             0         0         0       8,062
 Abbott, Tony         6              0         0         1       2,115
 Abbott, III, Francis 79             9         8         11      374,602
```

Comment: There is most definitely a way. 
The question is what have  you tried so far?

Comment: Can you use text-to-columns?

Comment: Yes I tried text to columns and updated the question to reflect that.